# How do I force my layout where one field has a flexible but the other are a set width?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to align three text fields in a row. The first field (bonusCode) will never have more than 8 characters in it, the third field (state) is always 2 characters, and the middle one (city) is the one I want to expand. I can't seem to figure out how to make it do that though. Here is what it looks like currently:

[image: Portrait View]
[image: Landscape View]

As you can see in the screenshots, as the layout size changes the gap between city and state increases. I want these to be the same distance apart. The expansion should be between bonusCode and City.

Here is my XML for the cell:

```
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListImage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainImageDescription"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image_taken" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
        android:text="@string/valueBonusName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListCategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
        android:text="@string/valueCategory" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListCategory"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListCode"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusCode" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListCity"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="12"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusCity"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListState"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusState"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the weight to all the textview inside the linear layout, Which divides the views as per the weight. Set `layout_weight` to the bonusListCode text view only and remove from state and city and it will work the way you want.

**Try this out:**

```
<RelativeLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bonusListImage"
    android:contentDescription="@string/mainImageDescription"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/no_image_taken" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bonusListName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
    android:text="@string/valueBonusName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bonusListCategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListName"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
    android:text="@string/valueCategory" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListCategory"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListCode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/valueBonusCode" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="@string/valueBonusCity"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListState"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="@string/valueBonusState"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked. Does this technically mean that the bonusCode field is the one that would expand sizes, since it's the one with weight? (Obviously not an issue with this use case, but curious for future apps).

Comment: @DJFriar, Check this description which will help you for the future. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relative Layout. For State viewkeep 'layout_alignParentRight' True. It will make the right edge of this view match the right edge of the parent. Also align city field to State field, For city field keep layout_toLeftOf to State view. You can keep padding in between.